# Sort an array with numerical values: the good way

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, array-broadcasting

First, let me give some context: I teach a first course in numerics for students who major in biology and mathematics. In this course, I try to give the students good habits for manipulating array of numbers, such as using the **ndarray** data structure of **NumPy**.

I am aware of the fact that no for loop should be used over a ndarray. I want to illustrate this statement with a standard sorting algorithm. Of course I know how to code this naively, and this is **not** what I want to do here.

I don't know how to do it with all the machinery of NumPy, but I thought I could search by myself. I found the [reference page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) for the `sort` function in NumPy, which has the following signature

```
numpy.sort(a, axis=-1, kind='quicksort', order=None)
```

This page links to the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L709-L823) of the function, which is useful. But then I'm lost! I don't understand where the magic happens in the following lines:

```
if axis is None:
    a = asanyarray(a).flatten()
    axis = 0
else:
    a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K")
a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
return a
```

So my question is: what does this piece of code do?

Comment: we don't see the values of `kind` and `order`

Comment: He didn't quote the function definition that accepts those parameters.

Comment: This function form delegates the task to method form.

Comment: Yes I see that, but then where is the source code of the method?

Comment: You really want to go into the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/core/src/npysort) of `ndarray.sort`?

Comment: @MSeifert thanks! So this is it? I should give up? The source code is either transparent (above) or cryptic (your link) ?

Comment: @bela83 No you don't need to give up. But most performance critical code in numpy is written as template, that template is converted to a C implementation which gets compiled as extension module and that extension is called eventually by the `np.sort` function. It's not really hard to understand but it takes a fair amount of C and Python knowledge.